# How to derive the conjugate of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a function,
$$f = \ell^{(\mathcal{\alpha})}_{ij}(a) = \max \left\{ \alpha a_{i}, (\alpha-1) a_{i} \right\}$$
I assume its conjugate has the form,
$$f^*(y) = \sup_{x \in dom f} (y^Tx-f(x)) = \sup_{x \in dom f} (y^Ta - \max \left\{ \alpha a_{i}, (\alpha-1) a_{i} \right\}) \\ = \begin{cases}
? \quad \\ 
\infty \quad \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
However I stopped here and don't know how to derive further.

In fact, I want to derive the proximal operator of $\ell^{(\mathcal{\alpha})}_{ij}(a)$, which I think maybe this is the intermediate step?

Comment: In your definition of the function $f$, what's the argument ? Is it $\alpha$ ? $A$ ? $(\alpha, A)$ ? Also, check your definition of $f^*$, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @dohmatob Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my description on this.